# Html does parsing error in my index.php (wordpress theme)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, parse-error

I am building my own wordpress theme. I'm not new to the html and pages related stuff but never did line of coding for php. I wanted to move on more complex cms - wordpress. Now I cant see why but my page throws out parsing errors for some reason.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ... on line ##

Here is part of my code including html in php:

```
     <?php

     if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        <h2>Title here</h2> /* says error is on this line */

        endwhile;

        else :
            echo '<p>No content found</p>'

        endif; /* also error is on this line */

     ?>
```

I'm using dreamweaver but that’s not key for solving this I guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

     if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
        <h2>Title here</h2> /* says error is on this line */
<?php
        endwhile;

        else :
            echo '<p>No content found</p>'

        endif; /* also error is on this line */

     ?>
```

This will help you....

Comment: Thx this pretty much solves it but there is still some unexpectible error on endif;  :/

Comment: Okey there was semicolon missing:D sorry guys and thx for fastest help ive ever had :D love this site!

Answer (score -1):

Try this. One echo and Semi colon was missing.

```
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    echo '<h2>Title here</h2>'; /* says error is on this line */

    endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif; /* also error is on this line */
```

Comment: Okey thanks much. This would solve it for sure. But wordpress should be able to fully support html in php docs :/ Can you also help me with this ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that much confident in wordpress. I just checked for the syntax.

Comment: Thx anyway :) I cant yet +1 but i would give you if i could